# How to erase part of text on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I clear a part of text when on focus?

I am adding "Not Valid" at end of text value when validation fails and I want to erase that part when user focuses on it.

```
$("#seMailTxt").val($email+" [Not Valid]");
```

Here is the on focus script I've written so far

```
$("#seMailTxt").focus(function(){
$email=$("#seMailTxt").val();
if ($email.indexOf(" [Not Valid]")>=0)
{
    //code to erase [Not Valid]
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#seMailTxt").focus(function(){
    $email=$("#seMailTxt").val();
    // This looks for that exact string at the end of the line
    // and strips it out
    $("#seMailTxt").val($email.replace(/ \[Not Valid\]$/, ''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `replace`.

```
$("#seMailTxt").focus(function(){
   var $email = $("#seMailTxt");   

   if($email.val().indexOf(" [Not Valid]")>=0) 
      $email.val($email.val().replace(" [Not Valid]",""));

});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/wuwg5/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#seMailTxt").val().replace("someString", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a replace on your text :

```
$email = $email.replace('your text to erase','');
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the function you already know `indexOf` can be used with `substring` to achieve the results you want. Take a look at:

```
$("#seMailTxt").focus(function(){
$email=$("#seMailTxt").val();
if ($email.indexOf(" [Not Valid]")>=0)
{
    $("#seMailTxt").val($email.substring(0, $email.indexOf(" [Not Valid]"));
}
});
```